# Spring Data mongodb Entity Callbacks doesn't work

Tags: mongodb, spring-data

I went through the [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/reference/html/#entity-callbacks) and couldn't find the way to enable entity callbacks. I have following code,

```
@Slf4j
@Component
public class EmployeeDetailCallback implements BeforeConvertCallback<EmployeeDetail>, BeforeSaveCallback<EmployeeDetail>, Ordered {
    @Override
    public EmployeeDetail onBeforeConvert(EmployeeDetail employeeDetail , String s) {
        log.debug("onBeforeConvert");

        return employeeDetail ;
    }

    @Override
    public EmployeeDetail onBeforeSave(EmployeeDetail employeeDetail , Document document, String s) {
        log.debug("onBeforeSave");

        return employeeDetail;
    }

    @Override
    public int getOrder() {
        return 101;
    }
}
```

and my config file is

```
@Configuration
@EnableMongoRepositories("com.test.model.api.employees.repository")
@Import(value = MongoAutoConfiguration.class)
public class DatabaseConfiguration {

}
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

shouldn't this be

```
EmployeeDetailCallback implements BeforeConvertCallback<EmployeeDetail>, BeforeSaveCallback<EmployeeDetail>
```

you define the callback type for a `ChemicalDetail` instead of `EmployeeDetail`.

**Edit 14.01.2021:**

Don't forget to add `@EnableMongoAuditing` to your Spring configuration. The [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/reference/html/#auditing) describes this in detail.

Comment: It was my mistake, I updated the question. Actual code is correct. it is still not being call. Do I need to setup anything else for these entity callbacks.

Comment: check my edit about the `@EnableMongoAuditing` annotation

Comment: You are right, I was missing `@EnableMongoAuditing`